# Is there a way to make nant build using .NET 4.5.1?

Tags: nant

We have just updated a project from 4.0 to 4.5.1 and we are having problems building it on NAnt. I just checked and it looks like it is dead.

Is there a way to build it using framework 4.5.1? The last version just supports up to framework 4.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach if you want to keep your existing build scripts / msbuild task: We're actually still running NAnt 0.85, but building directly with .Net 4.  In order to support newer framework versions, you need to do two things:

Firstly, edit `nant.exe.config`.  There is a section dealing with the frameworks - you'll see entries for `net-2.0`, `net-4.0` etc.  Find the one for `net-4.0` and duplicate it.  Then go through and update the paths/.Net version numbers as needed.

Secondly, at the start of your build script, specify which framework you want to use:

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-4.5" />
```

You can switch between frameworks as you wish during the build - parts of our legacy system switch between .Net 2 and .Net 4 as needed.

Comment: I've used this technique to add net-4.5 and net-4.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the NANT [MSBUILD](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/msbuild.html) task, we use the NANT [EXEC](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/exec.html) task and invoke the MSBUILD.exe directly by passing the attributes

1. "program" - location of the (v3.5, 4.0, 4.5) msbuild.exe
2. "command line" - location of csproj or solution file, additional properties

This way we control which version of MSBUILD we use and does not depend on NANT supporting the latest framework. On a side note, if you want to handle incremental builds in this scenario then you should pass the MSBUILD build/rebuild argument as a property to the exec task instead of hardcoding.